# Count duplicate items in a List<string> and save them in different files (Or Lists/arrays/strings)

Tags: c#, sorting, email

I need to count the duplicate values in List and save them in different files. With the name of file containing the email provider and number or duplicates.

The list always changes and has different values but it can look like that:

```
List<string> email_domains = new List<string>()     
{
    "gmail.com",
    "gmail.com",
    "outlook.com",
    "outlook.com",
    "outlook.com",
    "outlook.com",
    "ineria.pl",
    "mail.ru"
}
```

The result i want to get is something like this:

```
gmail.com [2]
outlook.com[4]
```

Comment: Getting counts of distinct values is one thing, you've shown no effort/code on what this "save them in different files" functionality is supposed to be

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, i should make the whole post clearer. I will try to do it better next time.

Answer (score 2):

```
var email_domains = new List<string>()
{
    "gmail.com",
    "gmail.com",
    "outlook.com",
    "outlook.com",
    "outlook.com",
    "outlook.com",
    "ineria.pl",
    "mail.ru"
};

var results = email_domains.GroupBy(x => x);
foreach (var domain in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} [{1}]", domain.Key, domain.Count());
}
```

Instead of `Console.WriteLine()` you can write to a file.

If you only want items that has at least one duplicate, add an additional condition:

```
foreach (var domain in email_domains.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} [{1}]", domain.Key, domain.Count());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = email_domains.GroupBy(_ => _)
                 .Select(g => new { Domain = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                 .Where(_ => _.Count > 1);
```

Instead of an anonymous type you could also select into a `Dictionary<string, int>`:

```
var result = email_domains.GroupBy(_ => _)
                  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using Linq to Objects:

```
var query = from item in email_domains
            group item by item into g
            where g.Count() > 1
            select new { email = g.Key, count = g.Count() };

foreach ( var item in query )
  File.WriteAllText($"c:\\{item.email} ({item.count}).txt", item.email);
```

The query select items grouped by same email having more than one occurences.

Then we save result to files.

You can replace `, item.email)` by what you want using WriteAllText or AllLines if you have multiline.